# error: incompatible types: byte[] cannot be converted to int. in Image

Tags: java, android, sqlite, blob

I try to display image in ImageView. type is BLOB into SQLite database but i found error in android studio is Error:(43, 220) error: incompatible types: byte[] cannot be converted to int .

This is my code in database class

```
public class Database {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dic.sqlite";
public static final String TABLE_FIRST = "en1_word";
public static final String TABLE_SECOND = "en2_word";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_WORD = "word";
public static final String COLUMN_MEAN = "mean";
public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String COLUMN_PIC = "pic";
public static final String COLUMN_FAVORITE = "favorite";}
```

and databasedao class

```
public class DictionaryDaoImpl implements DictionaryDao {
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
public DictionaryDaoImpl(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
    this.sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteDatabase;

}
@Override
public Word getWordById(int id) {
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Util.getCurrentTableName(),new String[]{Database.COLUMN_ID, Database.COLUMN_WORD, Database.COLUMN_MEAN, Database.COLUMN_FAVORITE,Database.COLUMN_CATEGORY ,Database.COLUMN_PIC},
            Database.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);

    int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_ID);
    int wordColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_WORD);
    int meanColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_MEAN);
    int favoriteColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_FAVORITE);
    int categoryColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_CATEGORY);
    byte[] picColumnIndex = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_PIC));

    Word word = null;
    if (cursor.moveToNext()){
        word = new Word(cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex),cursor.getString(wordColumnIndex), cursor.getString(meanColumnIndex), cursor.getInt(favoriteColumnIndex)==1,cursor.getString(categoryColumnIndex), cursor.getBlob(picColumnIndex));
    }
    return word;
}
```

and word class

```
public class Word {
private int id;
private String word;
private String mean;
boolean isFavorite;
private byte[] pic;
private String category;

public Word(int id, String word, String mean, boolean isFavorite, byte[] pic, String category) {
    this.id = id;
    this.word = word;
    this.mean = mean;
    this.isFavorite = isFavorite;
    this.pic = pic;
    this.category = category;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getWord() {
    return word;
}
public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}
public String getMean() {
    return mean;
}
public void setMean(String mean) {
    this.mean = mean;
}
public boolean isFavorite() {
    return isFavorite;
}
public void setIsFavorite(boolean isFavorite) {
    this.isFavorite = isFavorite;
}
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}
public byte[] getPic() {
    return pic;
}
public void setPic(byte[] pic) {
    this.pic = pic;
}
```

Comment: Where does the exception be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this `cursor.getBlob(picColumnIndex)` the `picColumnIndex` should be of type `int` whereas you have defined it as `byte[] picColumnIndex`

Instead of `byte[] picColumnIndex = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_PIC));` I believe you want `int picColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_PIC);`

Comment: I was about to say that

Comment: OK. I confuse . I can do it. Than you.